# VSCode Breakpoint in Serverless ExpressJS Typescript App Doesn't Work

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, serverless-framework

I'm unable to hit a breakpoint set in VSCode in my ExpressJS app written in typescript that uses the serverless-framework to deploy the code to an AWS Lambda.

I'm using the serverless-plugin-typescript to compile the typescript into a `.build` folder where the map files are generated and stored alongside compiled js files.

My debugger runs `serverless offline` to run the program locally. If I set the breakpoint in the `.build/src/controllers.js` file it will hit that breakpoint, but not if I set it in the uncompiled version.

My project folder structure is as such:

```
api/
--.build/
---- src/
------ config/
------ controllers/
--------- controller.js
--------- controller.js.map
------ interfaces/
------ services/
------ index.js
-- src/
---- config/
---- controllers/
------ controller.ts
---- interfaces/
---- services/
---- index.ts
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": ".build",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "rootDir": "./",
        "paths": {
            "*": [
                "node_modules/*"
            ]
        }
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

serverless.yaml

```
service: api

plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-typescript
  - serverless-offline

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs14.x
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221
  memorySize: 192
  timeout: 10
  versionFunctions: false
  region: us-east-1
  profile: xxxxxxx
  stage: dev
  environment:
    NODE_ENV: ${opt:env, 'local'}
  iam:
    role:
      statements:
        - Effect: 'Allow'
          Action:
            - 'dynamodb:*'
          Resource:
            - '*'

custom:
  serverless-offline:
    noPrependStageInUrl: true

functions:
  express:
    handler: src/index.handler
    package:
      include:
        - src/**
    events:
      - http:
          method: ANY
          path: /{proxy+}
          cors: true
      - http:
          method: ANY
          path: /
          cors: true
```

launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
     {
      "name": "API Debug",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/api",
      "runtimeExecutable": "node",
      "runtimeVersion":"14.17.0",
      "runtimeArgs": ["--lazy"],
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
      "args": [
        "offline",
        "--noPrependStageInUrl"
      ],
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/api/node_modules/.bin/serverless",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "smartStep": false,
      "stopOnEntry": false,
      "outFiles": [
        "${cwd}/.build/src/**/*"
      ],
      "protocol": "inspector",
      "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "development"
      },
      "autoAttachChildProcesses": true,
     },
    ]
}
```

```
VSCode Version: 1.60.0
TypeScript 4.3.5
Node 14.x.x
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Changed

```
"outFiles": [
        "${cwd}/api/.build/src/**/*"
      ],
```

to

```
"outFiles": [
        "${workspaceRoot}/api/.build/src/**/*"
      ],
```

And it fixed the problem

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Yeah, doesn't work. I still can only break in the source map file. Breakpoints are unbounded in the .ts file.